# finding different linear transformation that satisfy a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've got this exercise that given a map ask to first verify if it's exist and is unique, otherwise, find 2 linear transformation that satisfy that map:

g(2,0,1) = (1,0,0) ; g(1,-1,0) = (0,1,0) ; g(4,2,3) = (3,-2,0)

g(  u  ) =    e1   ; g(   w  ) =    e2   ; g(  v  ) = 3e1 -2e2

first:

how do i check that is not unique? the proof of linearity tells me that is possible but not that is unique, i suppose by the fact that u,w,v are not a base, but i would need a more solid explanation, i imagine that if the pre-image vector form a space bigger like R3 and the image form R2, it's like some vectors collapse into a vector in R2, is this a valid way to explain why some map are not defined by an unique linear transformation?

Second:

how could i extract some example of a linear transformation that satisfy that map?

thank for you time!

Comment: What do you mean by "the proof of linearity tells me that is possible"? and "pre-image vector"? and "form a space bigger"? and "the image form R2"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given vectors $u_1,\dots,u_p\in U$ and $v_1,\dots,v_p\in V,$

- there exists (at least) a linear map $g:U\to V$ such that
  $$g(u_i)=v_i\quad\forall i=1,\dots,p$$ iff every linear relation between the $u_i$'s is satisfied by the $v_i$'s, i.e. iff $\forall(\lambda_i)_{=1}^n\in K^n,$
  $$\sum_{i=1}^p\lambda_iu_i=0\implies\sum_{i=1}^p\lambda_iv_i=0.$$
- such a map $g$ is then uniquely defined *only on the subspace $U_0\subset U$ spanned by $u_1,\dots,u_p$*, by: $\forall(x_i)_{=1}^n\in K^n,$
  $$g\left(\sum_{i=1}^px_iu_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^px_iv_i,$$
  and this definition can be completed by an arbitrary linear map (e.g. the zero map), from a complement subspace of $U_0$, to $V.$ The map $g$ is therefore unique iff $U_0=U.$

In our example, the only linear relation between the $p=3$ vectors $u_1=(2,0,1),u_2=(1,-1,0),u_3=(4,2,3)\in U=K^3$ is$$u_3=3u_1-2u_2,$$ and this relation is satisfied by the vectors $v_1=(1,0,0),v_2=(0,1,0),v_3=(3,-2,0)\in V=K^3:$
$$v_3=3v_1-2v_2,$$
hence there exist linear maps $g:U\to V$ such that $g(u_i)=v_i\quad\forall i=1,2,3.$
Such a map is uniquely defined only on the plane $U_0\subset U$ with basis $(u_1,u_2)$ by
$$\forall(s,t)\in K^2\quad g(su_1+tu_2)=sv_1+tv_2,$$
i.e.
$$\forall(y,z)\in K^2\quad g(2z-y,y,z)=(z,-y,0).$$
It is not unique since $U_0\subsetneq U.$ A complement of $U_0$ is for instance the line spanned by the vector $u_4:=(1,0,0).$ Any choice of a vector $v_4\in V$ determines a solution $g:U\to V,$ by
$$\forall(t,y,z)\in K^3\quad g(2z-y+t,y,z)=(z,-y,0)+tv_4,$$
i.e.
$$\forall(x,y,z)\in K^3\quad g(x,y,z)=(z,-y,0)+(x+y-2z)v_4.$$

Comment: Can the today-downvoter please explain how they believe I could improve my answer? (But this looks more like serial downvoting - 9 in two days - which will then be automatically reversed.)

Answer (score 1):

For uniqueness, you need to know where every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ goes, uniquely.  If the 3 vectors where you have a mapping form a basis, that is necessary and sufficient.  It doesn't matter where they go to, it just matters that the 3 vectors in the preimage span the domain.